# Example of res judicata and collateral estoppel in the US

Tags: united-states, civil-procedure, civil-judgment

I know that res judicata, also known as claim preclusion, prohibits lawsuits involving the same cause of action and the same parties if the court has entered a final judgment on the merits. On the other hand, collateral estoppel, also known as issue preclusion, prohibits the same issue of fact or law to be litigated again. I'm confused about how these two concepts apply to a real scenario. What's an example of a scenario in which these two concepts apply vs. (one apply and the other doesn't apply)?